# How to implement Google Analytics tracking code with ClientId into PHP footer?

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am looking for a way to integrate ClientId created by Google into custom dimension in Google Analytics. I have found the instructions, but it is not working for me. I am not sure about how to install the tracking code correctly.

Here is the code to implement:

```
        ga(function(tracker) {
          var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
          ga('set', 'dimension2', clientId);
        });
```

Here is my current Google Analytics tracking code:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXXXX', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

        ga(function(tracker) {
          var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
          ga('set', 'dimension2', clientId);
        });

</script>
```

Any idea what is wrong? Did I implement the function which gets ClientId wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. Here is the code I now use in my Wordpress custom functions.php file.

```
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ GOOGLE ANALYTICS START ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

// google analytics userid variable
function google_analytics_tracking_code(){
    global $userId;
    $userId = get_current_user_id();
    if (!isset($userId)) {
        $userId = $_SESSION['xxx'];
    }
    ?>

    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            <?php
            // New Google Analytics code to set UserId and ClientId.

            if (isset($userId)) {
                $gacode = "ga('create', 'xxx', 'auto', {'userId': $userId});";
                echo sprintf($gacode, $userId);
            }     
            else {
                $gacode = "ga('create', 'xxx', 'auto');";
                echo sprintf($gacode);
            }?>
            ga('set', 'dimension1', '<?php echo $userId; ?>');

            // Get google client id
            var ga_client_id = null;
            ga(function(tracker) {
                ga_client_id = tracker.get('clientId');
                ga('set', 'dimension2', ga_client_id);
            });

            // Set ramdom session id
            var rand_session_id = null;
            rand_session_id = new Date().getTime() + '.' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(5);
            ga('set', 'dimension3', rand_session_id);

            // Get local time as ISO string with offset at the end
            var hit_timestamp = null;
            var now = new Date();
            var tzo = -now.getTimezoneOffset();
            var dif = tzo >= 0 ? '+' : '-';
            var pad = function(num) {
                var norm = Math.abs(Math.floor(num));
                return (norm < 10 ? '0' : '') + norm;
            };
            hit_timestamp = now.getFullYear() 
                + '-' + pad(now.getMonth()+1)
                + '-' + pad(now.getDate())
                + 'T' + pad(now.getHours())
                + ':' + pad(now.getMinutes()) 
                + ':' + pad(now.getSeconds())
                + '.' + pad(now.getMilliseconds())
                + dif + pad(tzo / 60) 
                + ':' + pad(tzo % 60);
            ga('set', 'dimension4', hit_timestamp);


            ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>

<?php
}
//add_action('wp_login', 'google_analytics_tracking_code', 10, 2);

// include GA tracking code before the closing body tag
add_action('wp_footer', 'google_analytics_tracking_code', 10, 2);

// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ GOOGLE ANALYTICS END ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Nice answer!, I can guess that in your solution CD 1, CD2 are on User level scope, and the CD3 on Session scope and the last one CD4, on hit scope

Answer (score 0):

Custom dimensions are sent along with an interaction hit. You set the dimension only after the pageview is tracked (and you do not send another interaction), so the custom dimension is never sent. Place your custom code after tracker creation but before the pageview call and this should work fine.